# invite friends in a dialog in a Facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to create a Facebook application that displays a friend invite dialog within the application using Facebook's Javascript API (FB.ui).

To do that I followed [this tutorial](http://rockurchin.com/blog/2010/11/closing-the-facebook-invite-widget/)

I have two problems:

1. The action url I've put in the request-form is "http://apps.facebook.com/appname/post_invite.php" 
   but I see that the iframe source after the post is "http://example.com/post_invite.php" 
   and when this iframe tries to do:
   parent.closeInviteWidget();
   I get an error saying:

   > "Permission denied for < http://example.com > (document.domain has not been set) to get     property Window.closeInviteWidget from < http://apps.facebook.com> (document.domain=< http://facebook.com>)."
2. The skip button inside the request-form opens the action url in a new window (new browser tab) and not post to itself like the invite button.

How can I fix those problems?

-------------------- UPDATE : --------------------------------

I've tried to do what ifaour said and changed the code to:

```
function inviteFriends(user_name, category_id, category_name)
{
    url = appBaseUrl + "/index.php?category_id=" + category_id;
    req = "<fb:req-choice url='" + url + "' label='Authorize My Application' />";
    content = user_name + " opened a new category called " + category_name + ". " + req;
    action = 'post_invite.php';

    fbmi_text = '<fb:request-form action="' + action + '" target="_self" method="post" invite="true" type="Invite" content="' + content + '" <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext="Invite yor friends" email_invite="false" import_external_friends="false" /> </fb:request-form>';

    FB.ui({
    method:'fbml.dialog',
    width:'750px',
    fbml:fbmi_text
     });
}
```

When I use FireBug and look at the invite form it looks like this:

```
<form id="req_form_4d20682f73ddb6e71722794" content="I've opened a new category called dsfsd. <fb:req-choice url='http://apps.facebook.com/appname/index.php?category_id=60' label='Authorize My Application' /> type="Invite" invite="true" method="post" target="_self" action="http://apps.facebook.com/appname/post_invite.php">
...
</form>
```

But I still get the same error:

> Permission denied for http://example.com (document.domain has not been set) to get property Window.closeInviteWidget from http://apps.facebook.com (document.domain=http://facebook.com)...

This are my app settings (I've added spaces because I can't add more links):
Site URL : http://appname.example.com/
Canvas Page : http://apps.facebook.com/appname/
Canvas URL : http://appname.example.com/
Canvas FBML/iframe : iframe
Post-Authorize Redirect URL : http://apps.facebook.com/appname/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a read of the official Facebook [document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form).

Also try using `action="http://appname.mydomain.com/post_invite.php"`.

EDIT: I've just realized! are you using IFrame or FBML as canvas type?!
If you are using IFrame then [fb:serverFbml](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/serverfbml/) is needed to use FBML within your IFrame.

Also please note that FBML will be [deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/):

> We are in the process of deprecating
>   FBML. If you are building a new
>   application on Facebook.com, please
>   implement your application using HTML,
>   JavaScript and CSS. You can use our
>   JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to
>   embedded many of the same social
>   features available in FBML. While
>   there is still functionality that we
>   have not ported over yet, we are no
>   longer adding new features to FBML.

Comment: When I write action="post_invite.php" facebook change it to - action="http://apps.facebook.com/appname/post_invite.php" when he renders it so it doesn't change anything. 
I'm using IFram. How should I do this if not with FBML? I can't put fb:serverFbml because I send to FB.ui only the content of the fbml...

Comment: Can you share your code? and how come it's the same? the action isn't pointing to your domain this time, right?

Comment: I've used your exact code on my test app and it worked just fine, please make sure that your post action link is within the domain settings in your application settings!

Comment: I've added my application settings to the question, should I change something?

Comment: I've also noticed that after the user is authorized (if session is empty) he returns to http://appname.mydomain.com/ and not the the application. Can it be for the same reason?

Comment: I use $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
     array('req_perms' => 'user_groups, user_location, user_hometown, user_education_history')
    );

Comment: what do u mean he returns to ... ? it's still in the iframe right? and the url u mentions IS the application?

Comment: anyway, here's my code: [fbtest.php](http://pastebin.com/wnyd1vzB) please note that I'm using codeigniter...and the permission are: `read_stream,email,user_birthday,publish_stream,user_groups`

Comment: Thank you for posting your code. I've tried to use it in my application but had the same problem has before when trying to close the dialog from the parent iFrame (Permission denied for <http://mydomain.com> (document.domain has not been set) to get property Window.closeInviteWidget from <http://apps.facebook.com> (document.domain=<http://facebook.com>)..). I've uploaded my test code : http://pastebin.com/5XCQ72s7 and the post_invite.php : http://pastebin.com/dqm1FXQg you can see it in action here - http://apps.facebook.com/zonetest/testinvite.php

Comment: correction - you can see the test in action here - http://apps.facebook.com/qrankshani/testinvite.php

Comment: Oh sorry about that!!! I've pasted an uncompleted code!! after the dialog button click event I have: `function closeInviteWidget() {$('.fb_dialog').hide();}` (but you are already aware of that) and the `http://fb.mydomain.com/fbtest/home/post/` action is retrieving this:`echo "<script>parent.closeInviteWidget();</script>";`

Comment: ah! i've just updated my answer, use the site URL in the action :s..I guess this is the issue, sorry about that!